# AmazonClientException: Unable To Load Credentials from any Provider in the Chain

Tags: java, mule, amazon-kinesis, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

My mule application writes json record to a kinesis stream. I use KPL producer library. When run locally, it picks AWS credentials from .aws/credentials and writes record to kinesis successfully.

However, when I deploy my application to Cloudhub, it throws AmazonClientException, obviously due to not having access to any of directories that DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain class supports. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html)

This is how I attach credentials and it looks locally in .aws/credentials:

```
config.setCredentialsProvider( new 
DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
```

I couldn't figure out a way to provide credentials explicitly using my-app.properies file.

Then I tried to create a separate configuration file with getters/setters. set access key and private key as private and then impement a getter:

```
public AWSCredentialsProvider getCredentials() { 
    if(accessKey == null || secretKey == null) { 
        return new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain(); 
    } 

    return new StaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(getAccessKey(), getSecretKey())); 
}
```

}

This was intended to be used instead of DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain class this way---

```
config.setCredentialsProvider(new AWSConfig().getCredentials());
```

Still throws the same error when deployed. 
The following repo states that it is possible to provide explicit credentials. I need help to figure out how because I can't find a proper documentation / example. 
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/blob/master/java/amazon-kinesis-producer-sample/src/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/producer/sample/SampleProducer.java

Comment: did you look into `PropertiesFileCredentialsProvider` yet?

Comment: I have not. Trying now.  Here is how I am trying to do this, please correct me if I am going in the wrong direction.    PropertiesFileCredentialsProvider localProperties = new PropertiesFileCredentialsProvider(credPath);
        localProperties.getCredentials();
        
        config.setCredentialsProvider(localProperties);

Answer (score 0):

I have Faced the same issue so, I got this solution I hope this will work for you also.

```
@Value("${s3_accessKey}")
private String s3_accessKey;

@Value("${s3_secretKey}")
private String s3_secretKey;

//this above  value I am taking from Application.properties file

BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(s3_accessKey, 
s3_secretKey); 

AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().
withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
    .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
    .build();
```